# matplotlib tick axis notation with superscript

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to produce some plot over the frequencies. I want to have an x-axis with superscript notation like in [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:EM_spectrum.svg). 
In addition I need vertical lines with vertical annotation separate kilo and mega Hz.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
band = np.linspace(0,10**12,100)
y = band

plt.plot(band,y)
plt.xlabel('Frequencies')

plt.vlines(10**3, min(y), max(y),colors = 'black', label = 'kilo Hz')
plt.vlines(10**6, min(y), max(y),colors = 'black', label = 'mega Hz')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I tried use [ticker](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter.set_powerlimits) but can't figure it out how to set up it. I tried to follow [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775040/matplotlib-axis-label-format) examples but got error like `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'ticklabel_format'`
Already spend quite a lot of time on it and don't know how to move forward.

In general I need the x-axis formatted in the similar way, than if `plt.xscale('log')` but I want to keep linear scale.

Comment: Can you show use the code that _doesn't_ work?

Comment: also, use `axvline` instead of `vlines` for your vertical lines.

Comment: I tried to use `matplotlib.ticker.Formatter` with different configurations, and I tried quite a lot of lines which doesn't exist anymore. Also for `set_major_formatter` I get errors like `object has no attribute`

Comment: Just a thought; if you are gonna have an x-axis spanning values (atleast) from 10**3 to 10**6 with a _linear_ scale, the distance between 10**5 and 10**6 will be 10 times the distance between 10**4 and 10**5, and 100 times (!!) the distance between 10**3 and 10**4. In the example you are linking to, the x-axis _is_ in fact a log-scale.

Comment: but what objects were you trying `set_major_formatter` on?  That is a method of `axis` (not `axes`) objects. ex: `yaxis = ax.get_yaxis()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define the tick-marks as strings and assign those:

```
mport numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
band = np.linspace(0,10**12,100)
y = band

plt.plot(band,y)
plt.xlabel("Frequencies")

plt.vlines(10**3, min(y), max(y),colors = 'black', label = 'kilo Hz')
plt.vlines(10**6, min(y), max(y),colors = 'black', label = 'mega Hz')

string_labels = []
for i in range(0,len(y),10):
    string_labels.append(r"$10^{%02d}$" % (i/10.0))

plt.xticks(np.linspace(0,10**12,10),string_labels)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. I really like your solution. It gives what I need. I though it can be done as some kind of formatting from the matplotlib level, but this is also nice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just shooting in the dark, but looks like xlabel takes a variety of options:

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel

When I went to:

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text

I noticed that there is a verticalalignment option.  Maybe that's what you need?

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately there us no solution to my problem as far as I see