# python + matplotlib: use locale to format y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, locale, axis

I want to format my y axis using matplotlib in python 2.7. This is what I tried:

```
ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_useLocale()
```

to format my y axis using `.` as thousands separator. Instead of having `10000`, I'd like to have `10.000`, and so on... but I can't find any example on how this work...

I could not find the documentation, on this page here there is no example or further documentation: http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter.set_useLocale

Or any other idea on how to format my axis?

thanks

Comment: You can do it like this: http://tiku.io/questions/1009459/how-to-format-axis-number-format-to-thousands-with-a-comma-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for more control than perhaps `set_useLocale()` can offer.  Therefore, drawing upon the example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775040/matplotlib-axis-label-format), I've used `FuncFormatter` with a simple function.  The `comma_format` function inserts the y-axis labels with a comma as a thousands separator and then replaces the commas with periods.  In this way, the y-axis labels can be formatted rather easily.

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

def comma_format(x, p):
    return format(x, "6,.0f").replace(",", ".")

ax = subplot(111)
xx = np.arange(0,20,1)
yy = np.arange(1000,10000,450)
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(comma_format))
plt.scatter(xx,yy)
plt.show()
```

[image]