# matplotlib colorbar formatting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been python code to plot 4 figures with colorbars. Since I use Texfonts, matplotlib renders the minus sign too wide. I therefore have a written a formatting function to replace the minus sign with a hyphen.
However, for some reason I can't apply the formatter to my colorbar.
I am getting an error:

```
cb.ax.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(myfmt))
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_major_formatter'
```

So below is the portion of my code where it breaks:
Do you have an idea how to force the colorbar to use my formatting function?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 

import re
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc 
from matplotlib.ticker import *
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
from list2nparr import list2nparr
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter 

plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = 'cm'
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 16
#plt.rcParams['font.weight'] = 'heavy'
plt.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False
#-----------------------------------------------------


def myfmt(x, pos=None):
  rv = format(x)
  if mpl.rcParams["text.usetex"]:
    rv = re.sub('$-$', r'\mhyphen', rv)

  return rv


fig,(ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4) = plt.subplots(nrows=4,figsize=(6,11),sharex = True, sharey=False)
data = list2nparr('radiant.txt')

lm  = data[:,14]
bet = data[:,15]
v   = data[:,16]
b   = data[:,18]
ejep = data[:,20]

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.1)

cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet') 
sc = ax1.scatter(lm, bet, c=ejep, s=10, cmap=cm, edgecolor='none',rasterized=True)
cb=plt.colorbar(sc,ax = ax1,aspect=10)
cb.formatter.set_powerlimits((0, 0))
cb.ax.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(myfmt))
cb.update_ticks()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib log-scale tick labels, minus sign too long in latex font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25210898/matplotlib-log-scale-tick-labels-minus-sign-too-long-in-latex-font)

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify the `xaxis`:

```
cb.ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(myfmt))
```

or `yaxis`:

```
cb.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(myfmt))
```

when setting the formatter.

Comment: I changed the line in my code from:
cb.ax.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(myfmt))

to:

cb.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(myfmt))

Now it runs smoothly without any errors but I noticed that it does not call the function at all. I put a line in my functions "print(rv)" and it does not print anything and the minus sign is still too big.

Comment: `plt.FuncFormatter(myfmt)` works or me as well as `ticker.FuncFormatter(myfmt)`. Double check that you actually hand in the right function.

Comment: I changed the line to:
`cb.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(myfmt))`

but still no effect. The function does not seem to be called at all, as it does not print anything. Plus the minus sign in the figure is still unchanged.

Comment: I would like to clarify that, if change the line:
`cb=plt.colorbar(sc,ax = ax1,aspect=10)`
to
`cb=plt.colorbar(sc,ax = ax1,aspect=10,format=ticker.FuncFormatter(myfmt))` and disable the line
`#cb.formatter.set_powerlimits((0, 0))` it works - changing the minus sign to hyphen but then I lose the exponent being placed at the top of the colorbar. However, if I enable the line 
`cb.formatter.set_powerlimits((0, 0))` I am getting the following error:
`cb.formatter.set_powerlimits((0, 0))
AttributeError: 'FuncFormatter' object has no attribute 'set_powerlimits'`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the following post:
[in the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25210898/matplotlib-log-scale-tick-labels-minus-sign-too-long-in-latex-font).

The solution is, instead of using `LogFormatter` one has to change the function to `ScalarFormatter` and define the \mhyphen as:

```
plt.rcParams["text.latex.preamble"].append(r'\mathchardef\mhyphen="2D')
```

So the following definition of the class worked for me:

```
class Myfmt(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter):
    def __call__(self, x, pos=None):
        # call the original LogFormatter
        rv =mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter.__call__(self, x, pos)

        # check if we really use TeX
        if mpl.rcParams["text.usetex"]:
            # if we have the string ^{- there is a negative exponent
            # where the minus sign is replaced by the short hyphen
            rv = re.sub('-', r'\mhyphen', rv)

        return rv
```

Then I just changed the line:

```
cb=plt.colorbar(sc,ax = ax1,aspect=10)
```

to

```
cb=plt.colorbar(sc,ax = ax1,aspect=10,format=Myfmt())
```

and I also enabled the line for placing a single exponent at the top of the colorbar:

```
cb.formatter.set_powerlimits((0, 0))
```

Thank you for for helping me to find the answer!