# Matplotlib uses glyph for '-' [U+2212] even with axes.unicode_minus False

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some data using a custom font for the axis of my matplotlib plot. This font does not have unicodes. Thus the error I have is:

```
Font 'default' does not have a glyph for '-' [U+2212], substituting with a dummy symbol.
```

I set, as suggested in the [official documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/unicode_minus.html), this:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False
```

However, I still get the warning above.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager
%matplotlib inline

# Font set
path = 'bahnschrift_reg.ttf'
prop = matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(fname=path)
mpl.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False

# Plot
f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.set_xscale('symlog', linthresh=0.001)
ax.set_xlim(-0.0001, 100) 
ax.set_ylim(0, 1.02)

# Set the font
for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
    label.set_fontproperties(prop)
    
plt.show()
```

[image]

The font I am using is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5wfbs6nrl4xtmfa/bahnschrift_reg.ttf?dl=0). Could you help me, please?

Comment: Maybe [edit .ttf font file to add in missing symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892693/edit-ttf-font-file-to-add-in-missing-symbol) helps?  Or changing the tick formatting ([Matplotlib log-scale tick labels, minus sign too long in latex font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25210898/matplotlib-log-scale-tick-labels-minus-sign-too-long-in-latex-font))?

Comment: The first one is a very good suggestion and I indeed followed that trick to do the plot ;D thx